# How to rerun failed step/secnario of a feature file in cucumber using webdriverio

Tags: selenium, cucumber, appium, webdriver-io

Please help on this. I am using the following cucumber opts:

```
cucumberOpts: {
    backtrace: false,
    failAmbiguousDefinitions: true,
    failFast: false,
    ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false,
    name: [],
    snippets: true,
    source: true,
    profile: [],
    require: [
        './features/step_definitions/given.js',
        './features/step_definitions/when.js',
        './features/step_definitions/then.js',
    ],
    snippetSyntax: undefined,
    strict: true,
    tagExpression: '@Test',
    tagsInTitle: false,
    timeout: 20000000,
},
```

Comment: Any progress on this Akhilesh?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/wdio-rerun-service Was recently released specifically for WebdriverIO and it works well with Cucumber Features/Scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the `wdio-cucumber-framework` then you can **only** rerun individual steps a specific number of times, like so:

```
module.exports = function () {
    /**
     * The following STEP DEFINITION will run maximum 3 times!
     * => 1 actual run + 2 reruns (on failure)
     */
    this.Given(/^Your step definition here$/, { wrapperOptions: { retry: 2 } }, () => {
        // ...
    });
});
```

**!Note:** `wrapperOptions` are *step-specific options* that are passed to the definition function wrapper. In our case, the `retry` option. You can read more about it in the Cucumber [DOCS](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/api_reference.md).

If you need control over the retry of a test-case, or test-suite, then unfortunately there isn't such a feature yet with Cucumber. But, if you want something like that, maybe use Mocha instead. Here are a [few examples](http://beta.webdriver.io/docs/retry.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your wdio config file.  It will retry the fail test two more time (total 3 time)

```
specFileRetries: 2,
specFileRetriesDelay: 5,
specFileRetriesDeferred: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

In `wdio.conf.js` 
set following  we are good to go, this configuration will rerun failed scenario from the beginning not just the failed step.

> ```
>  runnerConfig: {
>     // Set the number of times to retry a failed scenario
>     retry: 2,
>   },
> ```

then

> ```
> cucumberOpts: {
>     retry: true,
>   },
> ```